# How to get info from NSData?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

I'm a new to iOS.

NSData:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "formatted_address" : "Proyezd Voskresenskiye Vorota, 3, Moscow, Russia, 109012",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 55.75622380,
           "lng" : 37.61855850
        }
```

I need only "formatted_address", could you help me to make a NSString in which will be address?
Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Where did you get the data? Did you try NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver?

Comment: [[foo objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"formatted_address"]; Dictionary Object, get Object associated for key "results" which looks like an array, get first object from that array ( objectAtIndex:0).. which is a dictionary.. get objectForKey formatted_address

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `NSData` is a JSON response, you need to create an `NSDictionary` to be able to access specific portions of the data. An `NSDictionary` just maps keys to values. To get the values you call `– objectForKey:`. In your case you have a dictionary as a value for the key "results". So in your case:

```
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [[results objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *formattedAddress = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"formatted_address"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the NSJSONSerialization class. There is a method to convert your data to a Dictionary:

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error;
```

With that, you should be able to retrieve your NSString by asking your newly created NSDictionary.